# Can I only display the Ubuntu system tray/bar on one monitor?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

I thought I'd find the answer to this question a little more easily, but I basically have three monitors and I only want that top bar to show on one monitor.

When I'm using VMware Workstation and have a VM full screened, I can't access the minimize, close, etc buttons on an application that's full screened within that VM, because my Ubuntu top system/menu bar is at the top of every screen. Gets very annoying.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do other applications such as Firefox, Chrom{e,ium}, terminals, or others show this same problem? Sounds like a bug in VMware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. However, if VMWare is full-screen, it should be *on top* of the stack, hiding the top panel. If it is not, this sounds like possibly a bug in VMware.

Comment: Gotcha. I think it's just VMware then. Other applications seem to use the system bar as part of the application, so using the bar is ok. However, in VMware, sometimes the bar appears on top of the VM's full screened window. Particularly if I'm clicking outside of VMware. To get the bar to disappear after getting back in the VM, I have to literally click the Ubuntu bar at the top and then it disappears instantly. (Not the VMware pull-down bar, btw.)

Comment: I think you're confusing "maximized" and "full screen" which are two different things. With "maximized" the title bar folds into the top panel. In full screen, the top panel is not visible.

Comment: Does full screen become unmaximized once you take the mouse out of the VM and put it onto a window outside of VMware such as Google chrome? I'm fully aware of what they mean but this doesn't look like normal behavior. It doesn't happen in windows. I may have just lacked clarification.

Comment: No. The only way to take the mouse out of a full screen window would be to move the pointer to another screen (if you have multiple), or tell VMware to ungrab input so you can Alt+Tab to raise a different window on same screen. Top panel may appear on top of full-screened window at that point, but would go away when focus is returned to the full-screened window.

Comment: I gotcha. Makes sense. So it looks like my problem is that when I return to the full screen window, the top panel doesn't go away unless I specifically click the top panel while in the full screen window. Sounds just like a bug as you mentioned I think. Thanks so much for the help.